# Does changing the definition of a random variable also changes the PDF function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We know that a random variable (RV), say $X$, maps each member of the sample space to the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

Also, we know that based on the definition of the RV, different sets of points can be selected in $\mathbb{R}$. For example, in tossing a coin, we can define the RV as $X(head)=0$ and $X(tail)=1$. Alternatively, we can define the RV like this $X(head)=-2$ and $X(tail)=2$, so we can define $X$ in many different ways, and based on these different definitions, different sets of points in the set $\mathbb{R}$ are selected.

1) The above-mentioned explanation is right for discontinues RVs, is it correct when we deal with continues ones?

2) if so, then we can change the interval of the continuous RV $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$ based on the definition of $X$. The question is if we change the definition of $X$ which changes the interval of $X$ on $\mathbb{R}$, does the PDF of $X$ also change? and if the answer is yes then we can have many different PDFs for a RV.

Comment: If you change the definition of a random variable then you may have a different random variable; the new random variable may not have the same distribution as the original random variable.  For example if the distribution (non-degenerate continuous or discrete) of $X$ is symmetric about $0$, then the distribution of $Y=-X$ will be the same even though the random variables are different

Comment: Can we have a sample space and define different RVs for it and consequently different distributions?

Comment: The domain and image are part of what a random variable is. The coin-tosses functions that you defined above are two different random variables. The distribution is a measure defined on the image. Therefore, the distribution of those random variables are also different functions. One is defined on subsets of $\{0,1\}$, while the other is defined on subsets of $\{-2,2\}$. It is true that sending $0\mapsto -2$ and $1\mapsto 2$ one gets that those measures are one the pull-back of the other. As a consequence you can model a fair coin using either variable.

Comment: My problem actually has to do with the sample space. I cannot find any relationship between the sample space, RV defined on this sample space and its distribution. For example, I keep asking myself how can I find a sample space for a normal Gaussian PFD function defined for the RV $X$?. If I ignore the sample space and just think about the relationship between the random variable $X$ and its distribution, it seems to me like a variable and its function and no randomness can be seen here